# AWS - Autoscaling and instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I have an `ubuntu` server `(ami-714ba518)` which has a webserver on it (`Apache` and `PHP`). It is connected to a `MySQL` server on `RDS`. I want to setup auto scaling when load goes above 60-70% , but I'm having trouble getting my head around how it works.

My concern is that, when a change is made to a file in server, how does that change reflect on the other instances that auto scaling has started?

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaling http servers assumes that they are stateless, meaning that the state of them is dedicated to persistence layer - database, and not to servers themselves. If one of your instances writes something on its disk, this data won't be available to autoscaled new instances. Changes like this do not replicate by autoscaling feature. You can achieve that with shared file system via EFS, though, but it won't be replication. It'll be a shared resource.

P.S. Automatic EFS volumes attachment described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mount-fs-auto-mount-onreboot.html

Comment: Can you autoscaling and centralize data from all instances in EFS?

Comment: You can, however you can't achieve that with autoscaling itself. You need to somehow attach volumes to your ec2 instances. It is possible and documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mount-fs-auto-mount-onreboot.html

Answer (score 1):

The `Autoscaling` doesn't replicate the changes from your host server. If you already done the changes in your site, then may be you can create Custom `AMI` from your existing `EC2` instance, and then use the same for launching new instances using autoscaling.

You need to use some common back-end service which will serve your changes to all of your web servers (existing or newly launched).

Take a look at [s3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or [efs](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/).